# Would there be a race condition when multiple Actors access/call Object class methods in Scala?

Tags: scala, akka

In Scala singletons are created using **Object** classes and when serval Akka actors call methods in particular **Object**, would race condition occur ?

Comment: One of the central ideas with actors is that an actor encloses some state and communicates with the world only via messages. If your actors are sharing some stateful object you may need to reconsider whether you are taking the right approach.

Comment: Yes, there's  nothing magic about actors that means you don't have to worry about concurrent access to shared state... "Doctor, it  hurts when I do this" / "Don't do that then".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the object holds state, then yes. It will require proper synchronization guards

Answer (score 1):

Agree with, S V's answer.  A convenient "guard" for values is to use [`Agent`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.0/scala/agents.html).  Reads are immediate, writes are asynchronous:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import akka.agent.Agent

val agent = Agent(5)

Future {agent send 12}
Future { agent send (_ + 4)}
Future { agent send (_ * 2)}
```